# PFQuery using matchesQuery with other PFQueries returning inconsistent results

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a PFObject (called Mini), with pointers to 5 other PFObjects. I narrow my query results by matching subqueries on these objects, e.g.

```
    [query whereKey:@"miniDetails" matchesQuery:miniDetailsQuery];
```

This works fine, however, when I add another query match (in this case for 'MiniConfigQuery'), I get no results. However, I know for a fact that there are results that match both queries. If I comment out the miniConfigQuery, I get results, even though their properties perfectly match the conditions of my miniConfigQuery.

```
+ (PFQuery *)queryAtPoint:(PFGeoPoint*)geoPoint
{
    PFQuery *query = [Mini query];
    [query includeKey:@"miniConfig"];
    [query includeKey:@"miniDetails"];
    [query includeKey:@"miniStats"];
    [query includeKey:@"assetData"];
    [query includeKey:@"user"]; 

    PFQuery *miniDetailsQuery = [MiniDetails query];
    [self setUpDetailsQuery:miniDetailsQuery];
    [query whereKey:@"miniDetails" matchesQuery:miniDetailsQuery];

    PFQuery *miniConfigQuery = [MiniConfig query];
    [self setUpConfigQuery:miniConfigQuery];
    [query whereKey:@"miniConfig" matchesQuery:miniConfigQuery];

    return query;
}

+ (void)setUpConfigQuery:(PFQuery *)query
{
    [query whereKey:@"isUnlocked" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    [query whereKey:@"isDeleted" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    [query whereKey:@"isPrivate" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
}
```

I have a few thousand objects in my table. Is it possible that the MiniConfigQuery only looks at a subsection of these objects, and therefore the results aren't part of the objects returned when calling the MiniDetailsQuery (which contains much more specific search results)? Any ideas why I am getting no results when including the MiniConfigQuery?

In theory I could apply the MiniConfig criteria to the PFObjects returned from the search, but this results in a lot of wasted objects, and is very impractical in my use case.

Comment: I suspect that all of the queries are being subject to the default limit of 100 results.  Set the limit of each of them to the max (which is 1000).  Queries that return more than 1k results will need to be further qualified in order to work.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately 1000 still isn't enough. It looks like I'll have to sort the results after they come in. It's a shame, since ideally it would perform the MiniDetailsQuery first, and then further query by MiniConfig parameters, before returning the results, rather than both at the same time and then ANDing them...